# Does RevenueCart handle pricing template from Play Store?

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, firebase-ab-testing, revenuecat, flutter-in-app-purchase

Does someone have a clue about how implementing pricing template from PlayStore through RevenuCat ?

I have a pricing template for an app on playStore.

- I charge 3$ for US customer.
- I charge 6€ for europe ones.

Is it handled automatically on revenuCat ?

Do we need to upgrade our RevenuCat account to access a premium feature handling this ?

**And by analogy :** How AB testing on pricing can be handled given the fact we use RevenuCAT ?